# Reading checkbox values from vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A few days ago I started using vue.js and trying to get the hang of it.

I've been fiddling quite a bit to get this easy example to work: reading the value of selected checkboxes in components with vue.js .

Please see my example on http://jsbin.com/gukoqo/edit?html,js,output

How can I let `selected` in the parent instance contain the selected values of the checkbox? E.g., filter_a and filter_c are selected, then `selected` should contain an array: `['filter_a', 'filter_c']`

I expected vue.js to make this very easy, but don't know yet how to. Anyone? :)

I'm using the latest vue.js (2.3.3 at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way.

```
Vue.component('facet-filter', {
  props: ['filter', 'checked'],

  template: `<div>
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input @change="$emit('change', filter.text, $event)" 
                       class="form-check-input" 
                       type="checkbox" 
                       :value="filter.text" 
                       :checked="checked" 
                       name="filters"> {{filter.text}}
              {{$props | json 2}}</label>
            </div>`,
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    filterFacets: [
      { id: 0, text: 'filter_a' },
      { id: 1, text: 'filter_b' },
      { id: 2, text: 'filter_c' },
      { id: 3, text: 'filter_d' },
    ],
    selected: [], // How can I let this contain ['filter_a', 'filter_b'] etc. when selected?
  },
  methods:{
    onChange(filter, $event){
      if ($event.target.checked)
        this.selected.push(filter)
      else {
        const index = this.selected.findIndex(f => f === filter)
        if (index >= 0)
          this.selected.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And change your template to

```
<div id="app">
  <facet-filter
    v-for="item in filterFacets"
    v-bind:filter="item"
    v-bind:checked="selected.includes(item.text)"
    :key="item.id"
    @change="onChange"
    >
  </facet-filter>
  <p><pre>data: {{$data | json 2}}</pre></p>
</div>
```

Updated [bin](http://jsbin.com/zoyucecuco/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciated! To be honest, I was a little afraid of this already :) It seems to add a lot of complexity for such a simple thing. I'll dive into your example.